# How to change Screen overlay after system ui mode changed(Fullscreen, hide navigation)?

Tags: android, overlay, fullscreen

I create overlay:

```
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    /*The parent view (actually the root view) the will be added in front of all the windows on the screen*/
    mOverlayView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_control, null);

        mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        mWindowSize = new Size(size.x, size.y);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    mWindowManager.addView(mOverlayView, params);
```

I need to move overlay if system UI Visibility changed. There is possibility to detect it([documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html)) for view but it not works for overlay. So I only need callback to detect if mode of device changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do it:

In Android there is `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` but it not works if there is not view which will has `match_parent` value of width or hight.

So I created such overlay and made it 1 px height and `match_parent` width and add   `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` to it.